# ¿Cómo obtener un dato específico fuera de un adaptador personalizao cuando se modifica un campo dentro de un ListView?

Tags: android

Tengo un listview que muestra diferentes campos, uno de ellos editable, digamos que el valor de facturas. Deseo obtener la suma de todos los campos mientras se modifica el dato que se encuentra dentro de un EditText que a su vez se encuentra dentro de un listview y este dentro de un adaptador personalizado. Se que con el evento addTextChangedListener del EditText puedo controlar mientras se modifica un dato, la pregunta es:

¿Cómo obtener fuera del adaptador personalizado la suma total de los campos mientras se modifica el valor de un EditText?

```
holder.et_collectionAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Modificado...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto:
Cuando llamo al adaptador personalizado, paso el textview y dentro del evento public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) realizo los cálculos y asigno el total, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
holder.et_collectionAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String mTemp = "";
            Float mTotal = 0.0f;
            if (holder.et_collectionAmount.length() > 0 && !holder.et_collectionAmount.getText().toString().equals(".")){
                for (int i = 0; i < mListView.getCount(); i++){
                    View view = mListView.getChildAt(i);

                    EditText et_collectionAmount = view.findViewById(R.id.et_collectionAmount);
                    mTemp = et_collectionAmount.getText().toString();
                    mTemp = mTemp.replace(",","");
                    mTotal += Float.parseFloat(mTemp);
                }
                textView.setText(formato.format(mTotal));
            } else {
                holder.et_collectionAmount.setText("0.00");
            }
        }
    });
```

Espero sea de ayuda para alguien.
Saludos